# doccument.images.length return 1

Tags: html, express, dom

I wonder why this happens , want to know if good or bad , if I use the console in my browser and type:

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName('img')
```

or

```
document.images.length
```

it should return all images in the page or length

if I do this in some websites return every image, but if i do this in my webpage (only return favicon) or apple.com (none) it shows limitations.

what makes this difference?

my application is a restful express 4 based website.

thanks

Comment: When you get an unexpected result in selecting element from page, you should consider check the actual html of the page from developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing . I will punch myself in the face saying:

if there are no more images on the document, then only will show the existent.

In my website, I do have img tags in my html code, but bootstrap removes those at the beginning (then get the image from the src and append to a div as background), so , no images.

In the case of apple.com website ... there are no img tags  they use

```
  <figures>
```

with a background-image. Which is interesting to know.